# AppLocker Exceptions being Ignored

Tags: gpo, applocker

I am trying to block .exe's from running out of the AppData folder with some obvious exceptions.

Testing it out, I have setup the default rules and a deny rule for C:\Users*\Appdata* with an single publisher exception (for now) for O=MICROSOFT CORPORATION, L=REDMOND, S=WASHINGTON, C=US.

However, Microsoft Teams, as an example, is still blocked.

Thought this would be simpler than it is and would appreciate any help.
Especially if AppLocker is not the correct way to do be doing this.

Thank you